# Train model with two columns and data split: Time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

Is it possible to train a model with a two column dataset? The dataset contains the columns "value" (which I'm trying to predict) and "timestamp" (Unix Timestamp).

I was able to load my dataset, but I'm stuck when it comes to trainin the model. On "Edit additional parameters" I choose "timestamp" as Time column and save it. 
When I press "Train model" now, I can't choose a feature column and the summary says "Data split: Automatic". But I've chosen Time column as data split.

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I don't think it has to do with you only having 2 columns, since I have a dozen or so, and the UI still displays "Data split: Automatic" despite splitting by timestamp/Time column. I am hoping it is a UI error, since AutoML Tables still is in beta mode...

Answer (score 0):

The "split: Automatic" is a bug that we are resolving. The data split will be based on timestamp if it's selected as timestamp split.

I just tested, two columns:

- label
- timestamp

works with using the timestamp column as split column and feature column.

Looks like the UI does not allow the timestamp being selected as the feature column. Could you post a stats screenshot for the timestamp column?